# GDM screen icon theme?

Tags: icons, gdm

Does anyone know which file configures the default icon theme (indicator and status icons) used in the top bar of the GDM screen on Ubuntu 20.04?

I looked inside the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` but it's not there.

(Please note, I am *not* looking for an extension to change the GDM icon theme).

Comment: Whats the Ubuntu version?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit the file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override`.
2. In the section...

   ```
   [org.gnome.desktop.interface:GNOME-Greeter]
   gtk-theme = "Yaru"
   icon-theme = "Yaru"
   cursor-theme = "Yaru"
   font-name = "Ubuntu 11"
   monospace-font-name = "Ubuntu Mono 13"
   ```
3. Replace the `icon-theme = "Yaru"` with the desired theme, such as Newaita...

   ```
   [org.gnome.desktop.interface:GNOME-Greeter]
   gtk-theme = "Yaru"
   icon-theme = "Newaita"
   cursor-theme = "Yaru"
   font-name = "Ubuntu 11"
   monospace-font-name = "Ubuntu Mono 13"
   ```
4. Save this file and exit your editor.
5. Then compile the gschemas...

   ```
   sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
   ```

Comment: Interesting, looking at the values of those settings in that file (and in other files in the same directory), I would rather expect (and call) them to be fallbacks, than overrides; what do you think?

Comment: They are Distribution Vendor's overrides of the default values (if present) stored in the `*.gschema.xml` files in this same folder. So the `gschema.override` files always override the `gschema.xml` files. Furthermore, `gschema.override` files starting with a higher number always override the files starting with a lower number. For example, `org.gnome.shell.gschema.xml` is overridden by `00_org.gnome.shell.gschema.override`, which is overridden by `10_gnome-shell.gschema.override`. The file name doesn't matter and any gsettings key can be in any file. Highest number takes prescience.

Comment: Wow, thank you, learned something important! Key being that they are used by the Ubuntu release to override Gnome defaults.